# Using cpp dll in c# project

Tags: c#, winapi, dll, dllimport

I have a win32 cpp dll, and a c# project (PROJ_1), that use dllimport to call win32 dll functions. This dll included into project PROJ_1 and has build action as copy to output dir.

Another c# project (PROJ_2) references PROJ_1
and PROJ_3 references PROJ_2.

So, now we have something like this PROJ_3->PROJ_2->PROJ_1(dll)

So, when i make build in VS 2010:
1. In bin of PROJ_1 i have win32 dll.
2. In bin of PROJ_2 too
3. But in PROJ_3 - no win32 dll exists

What is the problem a how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

If the projects are in one VS solution, do you have dependencies between projects correctly defined (right click project -> Project dependencies)? Are all the projects built for the same target architecture (64/86)?

As side question - Did you consider writing C++/CLI wrapper?

Comment: Is it the best practice to use  C++/CLI wrapper vs dllimport?

Comment: @cyssima I wouldn't go that far, but I have better experience with C++/CLI than with DllImport. There are situations where DllImport is impossible to use/would be very hard to use (for example complex APIs that return and accept objects, generic classes etc.).

Comment: Ah. Ok. So, going to my question: this is a one solution; dependencies are correct; actually target platform for these projects is x86, but in this solution there are others projects who builds in AnyCPU configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest, you add that unmanaged DLL to the PROJ3 solution and in the properties set "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy always"

Answer (score 0):

You could check the 'Copy Local' property of the reference to PROJ_2.
In PROJ_1, add the win32 dll to your solution (no reference, just add it as a file just like a class in your solution) and set the properties Build Action = Content, Copy to Output Directory = Copy always.